# AMPL not running

Tags: ampl

Why am I facing this error when executing my code?

```
ampl: model Assingment_3.mod;

Assingment_3.mod, line 11 (offset 202):
    syntax error
context:  1  >>> 30 <<<
```

```
# Define the set of boxes
set BOXES := 1..8;

reset; # Clears all previous AMPL definitions

set TRUCKS := 1..2;

param Volume := 
1 30
2 60
3 70
4 20
5 10
6 10
7 50
8 50;

param Priority :=
1 2 # Box 1 has priority 2 (Food)
2 3 # Box 2 has priority 3 (Urgent)
3 2 # Box 3 has priority 2 (Food)
4 2 # Box 4 has priority 2 (Food)
5 3 # Box 5 has priority 3 (Urgent)
6 3 # Box 6 has priority 3 (Urgent)
7 1 # Box 7 has priority 1 (None)
8 4; # Box 8 has priority 4 (Urgent Food)

var x{BOXES, TRUCKS} binary;

maximize TotalPriority: sum{i in BOXES, j in TRUCKS} Priority[i] * x[i,j];

subject to VolumeConstraint{j in TRUCKS}: 
    140 <= sum{i in BOXES} Volume[i] * x[i,j] <= 160;

subject to OneTruckEach{i in BOXES}: 
    sum{j in TRUCKS} x[i,j] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In AMPL model and data are declared separately. The way you have sets `BOXES` and `TRUCKS` you are defining the sets at the same time you fix their values. However, for parameters such as `Volume` and `Priority`, you need to declare them before load the data from a file or from a data section as follows:

```
set BOXES := 1..8;
set TRUCKS := 1..2;
param Volume{BOXES}; # Declare Volume
param Priority{BOXES}; # Declare Priority

var x{BOXES, TRUCKS} binary;

maximize TotalPriority: sum{i in BOXES, j in TRUCKS} Priority[i] * x[i,j];

subject to VolumeConstraint{j in TRUCKS}: 
    140 <= sum{i in BOXES} Volume[i] * x[i,j] <= 160;

subject to OneTruckEach{i in BOXES}: 
    sum{j in TRUCKS} x[i,j] = 1;

# Load the data for Volume and Priority
data;
param Volume := 
1 30
2 60
3 70
4 20
5 10
6 10
7 50
8 50;

param Priority :=
1 2 # Box 1 has priority 2 (Food)
2 3 # Box 2 has priority 3 (Urgent)
3 2 # Box 3 has priority 2 (Food)
4 2 # Box 4 has priority 2 (Food)
5 3 # Box 5 has priority 3 (Urgent)
6 3 # Box 6 has priority 3 (Urgent)
7 1 # Box 7 has priority 1 (None)
8 4; # Box 8 has priority 4 (Urgent Food)
model;

option solver gurobi;
solve;
```

This will produce the output:

```
Gurobi 11.0.1: optimal solution; objective 20
0 simplex iteration(s)
```

Note however that for more flexibility, declaring the sets with just `set BOXES; set TRUCKS;` and then also loading the data for them in the data section would be recommended unless it is guaranteed that they will be static.